# What are all the ways to expose an Azure Ad authenticated API to third party apps

Tags: azure, api, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I have implemented an API that is Azure AD protected and want to expose those APIs to external applications. What is the secure way to expose them

Comment: What kind of 3rd party apps you would like to provide access?

Comment: it can be a web app or web api

Comment: Did you refer to this document before? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-overview

Comment: thanks, I have gone through them and is it possible to implement multiple authentications on API or APIM

Answer (score 0):

If you want an external web app to call a web api, please refer to this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-overview

You will need to have your web app authenticate to Azure AD, and provide the token to the web api.

Comment: thanks, I have gone through that and is it possible to implement multiple authentications on API or APIM in Azure like both AD and AuthO